# Не работают заголовки h1...h6

Tags: html

Подскажите, почему могут не работать теги заголовков h1...h6? То есть при добавление любого заголовка в верстку, оформление никак не меняется, текст остается таким же, как и без h1...h6.

Сайт - самопис, никакая cms не используется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А как дела обстоят со стороны CSS? У вас случайно резета никакого нет (сброса стилей reset.css)? Сами собой стили элементов одинаковыми не становятся.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Именно в этом и была проблема. Мейер. Проблема решена.

Answer (score 0):

А код в студию можно?!

И в каком редакторе пишется сам `html`?

Это голый `html` или прикрученный уже к чему то?

Comment: notepad++

Что значит "прикрученный"?

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<?php include('include/style.php');?>

</head>

<body>

<div class="main">

<?php include ('include/header.php');?>

<div id="content_border">

<h1>Заг</h1>//Не работает

 <div id="content_text">

  <div class='image'>

   <img class="main_pic" src="images/for_main/<?php echo(mt_rand(1,37)); ?>.jpg" />

  </div>

 </div>

</div>


<?php include ('parts/footer.php'); ?>

</div>

</body>

Comment: style.php тоже не помешал бы)

Comment: Блин php не дружу я с ним, но верстка знакома))
И так вставил код я в свой редактор заголовок отобразился как нужно. попробуй style.php закомментить и проверь. Потому что без него у меня работает твой код.

Comment: Проблема решена. Там был файл сброса стилей от Мейера. Не посмотрел в него.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>текст</h1>
<h2>текст</h2>
<h3>текст</h3>
<h4>текст</h4>
<h5>текст</h5>
<h6>текст</h6>
```

попробуйте правильно вот так они и ставятся, может у вас просто какия то теги или скрипты рядом стоят, если же так не работает опробуйте в ксс записать.

```
.bigtext p {
    font-size:14px; //указываете сколько px
}

.sidenote {
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: Прочитайте комментарии выше.